# Accessing the C:\ drive on azure VPS with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Basically I have a asp.net site hosted on windows azure, and I also have a virtual machine hosted there. Is it possible for me to read/write files to the disk on the virtual machine from my website?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 if that's any help at all. Sorry for the possibly vague question, if you need more info i'll happily try to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is your site hosted - Azure Web Sites, or Azure Cloud Service? If it is a cloud service, it is possible to have such shared folder accessible from cloud service. If your site is in Azure Web Sites, currently it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Since you want to access the VM's drive, and you have complete control over the VM it's easy.

**Server**

Expose your VM's drive using WebDAV.  It's a HTTP API for file sharing.

Here's a WebDAV setup guide for Windows: http://mythoughtsonit.com/2013/05/deploy-a-file-server-in-the-cloud-webdav-on-windows-azure/

**Client**

If you are using Windows Azure Websites (very restrictive), your only option on your ASP.NET site is to add C#/VB code to read/write from the WebDAV share.  Here's some .NET WebDAV clients:

- https://github.com/kvdb/WebDAVClient
- http://webdavnet.codeplex.com/
- http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/

If you are using a Windows Azure Cloud Project and have a Web Role (more flexible), on that web role you could make a startup task which maps the WebDAV as a network drive and use normal System.IO.File code.  I think this is easier than the WebDAV client stuff, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I came to a similar conclusion to @Yoshi. However, when trying to map the share to a drive on the instance hosting the web role via a startup task, I found that this requires WebDav client to be installed. This is installed as part of the Desktop Experience feature. To date I have been unable to install this using a startup task as it requires a reboot.

I have tried writting a startup task that includes the steps from [this article](http://www.sepago.de/e/marcel/2013/07/19/adding-feature-desktop-experience-on-windows-server-2012-breaks-configmgr-task-sequence-ae-a-workaround) but cannot get it to work so far.

Has anyone else managed this?